# Apple App Store: INSTALL_ERROR_DISTRIBUTION_SIGNED_BY_APPLE

Tags: app-store

Anyone else getting this error when trying to download an app from the new Apple Mac App Store?

INSTALL_ERROR_DISTRIBUTION_SIGNED_BY_APPLE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same error because my OS time/date was not correct.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this problem while trying to update an application, but my problem was not an unsynchronized clock (`ntpdate -q time.apple.com` showed a maximum offset of 0.022479).

I found a hint in an [a thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15036653#15036653) on one of Apple’s discussion forums that the problem might be related to certificate status checking settings. Modifications in this area resolved the problem for me. In the *Keychain Access* application, after selecting the **Keychain Access** menu > **Preferences…** menu item, and switching to the **Certificates** tab (close this preferences window when done making any changes), I ended up changing both my OCSP and CRL settings from “Require if Cert Indicates” (which seemed like a useful, “strict” setting to me), to “Best Attempt” (the Priority remained “Require Both”).

It seems that the “Require if Cert Indicates” and “Require for All Certs” options are normally grayed-out (I originally set them back on a machine running Tiger, which was migrated to this Snow Leopard machine). I found that you can hold down Option while clicking on the popup button (a.k.a drop-down list) to enable and select these options though. I may go back and try to determine which setting (OSCP or CRL) was strictly necessary.